# add css properties in my div

Tags: html, css

Maybe this is an easy stuff for all web designers out there. So here goes. I just want to add a padding-left property to my div which is inside an div element.

This is the structure of my html

```
<div id="content-sub">
    <form action="/en/contact"  method="post" id="contact-mail-page">
        <div> <!-- *This part is where I want to add the property padding-left*-->
            You can leave a message using the contact form below.
            ...........
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Points to consider:

1. If you're suggesting of adding a class name or id name. No can't do cause I can't find/don't know the location of the contact form file so I can only add this property in the style.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some CSS to add:

```
#contact-mail-page > div { padding-left: 10px; }
```

This will only apply to the first level of children in the form element, so any divs inside that div tag will not get the padding applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#content-sub div { padding-left : 10px;}
```

Comment: Not it will with your edit! :p  You had the `>` selector previously, which wouldn't select past the form

Comment: :-) that was a typing mistake

Answer (score 1):

Here is you can do

```
#content-sub div {
//add stuff
}
```